# How to make an event inside the onClick method in android

Tags: android, android-layout

My requirement is on the click of a image i should give an alert by alertbuilder.
    It is happening perfectly fine.In the alertbuilder i am referring one layout.Then i am referring the ids of widgets.Then within this scope of onclick method iam making actions for these widgets.

```
holder.source.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Source",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog = new Dialog(RecordingActivity2.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Source File");
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);
                ImageButton im = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.close);
                im.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    **If i am making actions here application is closing unexpectedly.**

                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
                }
            });
```

Here is my logcat output

```
07-04 17:25:29.923: E/AndroidRuntime(1928): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 17:25:29.923: E/AndroidRuntime(1928): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-04 17:25:29.923: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):     at com.pdev.activities.RecordingActivity2$VehicleAdapter$1.onClick(RecordingActivity2.java:209)
07-04 17:25:29.923: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
07-04 17:25:29.923: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
07-04 17:25:29.923: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-04 17:25:29.923: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-04 17:25:29.923: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-04 17:25:29.923: E/AndroidRuntime(1928):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
```

Comment: What type of event ypu are rtying to make ? and give us your code so can we can review !!:)

Comment: is R.id.close inside activity_read?

Comment: Actually i want to create medi player inside that.Before that i tried for toast message .That itself not happening correctly

Comment: Can you specify what is being done within the onClick? Since the log cat specifies the error is within the onClick method.

Comment: FYI, that ImageButton is not part of your dialog.

Comment: did you checked whether 'ImageButton im = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.close);' working fine?

Comment: If i does not make any action for imagebutton.It is displaying correctly

Comment: @Nandhiya Is your image button inside the layout activity read ?

Comment: Inside the on click just if click close it should close that dialog thats it

Comment: Then your imagebutton is not instantiated

Comment: if R.id.close is not in activity_read, then it wont be instantiated this way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
ImageButton im = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.close);
```

To

```
ImageButton im = (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
```